# Loopless function algorithm for binary search tree in-order traversal

Tags: algorithm, ocaml, lazy-evaluation

According to [Pearls of Functional Algorithm Design](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pearls-Functional-Algorithm-Design-Richard/dp/0521513383/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1397645720&sr=8-1&keywords=functional%20pearls), **loopless function** is

> Imagine a program for generating combinatorial patterns of some kind,
>   patterns such as the subsequences or permutations of a list.
>
> Suppose that each pattern is obtained from its predecessor by a single
>   transition. For subsequences a transition *i* could mean *insert* or
>   *delete* the element at position *i*. For permutations a transition *i* could mean “swap the item in position *i* with the one in position *i − 1*.
>
> An algorithm for generating all patterns is called **loopless** if the
>   *first transition is produced in linear time* and *each subsequent transition in constant time*. Note that it is the transitions that are
>   produced in constant time, not the patterns; writing out a pattern is
>   not usually possible in constant time.

---

For example, we can have our binary search tree `pre-order` traversal like this:

```
type 'a bst = Empty | Node of 'a bst * 'a * 'a bst

let rec preorder = function
  | Empty -> []
  | Node (l, x, r) -> x::preorder l @ preorder r
```

In order to make the `pre-order` traversal *loopless*, we need to prepare the first transition:

```
let prepare t = [t]
```

Then we define the `step_f` which is the function for the subsequent transition:

```
let step_f = function
  | [] -> None
  | t::tl -> 
    match t with
      | Empty -> failwith "wrong"
      | Node (Empty, x, Empty) -> Some (x, tl)
      | Node (Empty, x, c) | Node (c, x, Empty) -> Some (x, c::tl)
      | Node (l, x, r) -> Some (x, l::r::tl)
```

Basically, `step_f` take out one element directly and prepare for the next transition which can be used in next step.

We can have a standard `unfold` function which wire the whole process

```
let rec unfold a =
  match step_f a with
    | None -> []
    | Some (b, a') -> b::unfold a'

let _ = unfold (prepare bst)
```

This loopless thing can naturally be used to construct lazy functions, etc.

---

My question here is **how to design a loopless function for bst in-order traversal?**

Note that the prepare process costs at most O(n) and step process costs O(1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can easily generate the in-order traversal in O(n) time, so one approach would be:

- Generate the in-order traversal and store it in a list
- Loop through the list, outputting each element

This takes O(n) to get to the first one, then O(1) for each one after.

---

O(n) in-order traversal can be done with something like this (in pseudo-code): (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-order_traversal#Implementations))

```
inorder(node)
  if node == null
    return
  inorder(node.left)
  store(node)
  inorder(node.right)
```

---

I don't really know OCaml, but I hope the fundamental idea still holds.